# How to correctly calculate the number of minutes from a certain moment?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

There is a start date for the process in string form:

```
'2020-03-02 06:49:05'
```

And the process completion date:

```
'2020-03-02 07:05:02'
```

Question:
What is the most correct way from the point of view of the approach - to calculate the difference (in minutes) between the start and finish of the process?
(if there are any built-in methods for this in `vue.js` or`nuxt.js`, it will be very interesting to learn about them as well.)

Comment: how about using some library like momentjs[https://momentjs.com/docs/]

Comment: Yes. The best method is to not do the calculation yourself and use a library. And also to think next time that this is such a common problem that this question might have been asked 1000 times on stackoverflow. So let me first check and then ask this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best way would be to use Javascript Date object,

```
d1 = '2020-03-02 06:49:05'
d2 = '2020-03-02 07:05:02'

diff_in_millis = Math.abs(new Date(d1) - new Date(d2))
diff_in_minutes = diff/60000
```

Comment: Maybe `Math.floor()` should be applied to the end result, if an integer count of *completed* minutes is required?

Comment: I have a problem in IE browser:
If I put this code console.log( startDate2 ); - I don't have any problem
http://joxi.ru/4AkL5KoHXBXGyr

But if I try to convert this data like in this case:
console.log( new Date(startDate2) );
I have that:
http://joxi.ru/LmGgJPehJ5J5pm
Why is it happening?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/), you can do something like this:

```
var duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
var minutes = duration.minutes();
```

More about duration in momentjs can be found [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)

Comment: You probably meant to name your variable `minutes` as it will contain the number of minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Create the date from the string using [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). It return the date in milliseconds, get the difference and convert that to Minutes.

See snippet below.

```js
const startTime= Date.parse('2020-03-02 06:49:05')
const endTime = Date.parse('2020-03-02 07:05:02')

// Difference in Minutes
const durationInMin= (endTime-startTime)/60000;

console.log({ startTime, endTime, durationInMin })

alert(`Process took: ${durationInMin} minutes`)
```

---

Note: For human readable dates, I have found [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) to be the most helpful. Given its lightweight compared to momentjs. And you could complete the same with the following.

```js
import { differenceInMinutes } from 'date-fns';

const startDate = '2020-03-02 06:49:05';
const endDate = '2020-03-02 07:05:02';
const durationInMin = differenceInMinutes( new Date(endDate), new Date(startDate));

console.log(`Duration:  ${durationInMin} minutes`);
```

At the cost of another dependence to the project of course, but if you are handling lots of human readable dates, it's worth it.